# Why did Ron ask such a question?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

Behind Umbridge's back, Harry and his team collected the names of students who were interested in joining Dumbledore's army:

> Hermione: I mean, it's sort of exciting, isn't it, breaking the rules?
>
> Ron: **Who are you and what have you done with Hermione?**

Why did Ron ask such question?

Comment: This type of question is [on-topic as per our meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11626)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an English language question rather than a science fiction one, but anyway...

This is a colloquial British phrase that means someone is behaving very unusually. You can find this on [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Who%20are%20you%2C%20and%20what%20have%20you%20done%20with) which defines the phrase as;

> Used to express astonishment when somebody says or does something completely out of character. The only possible explanation is that they've been replaced by an alien shape-shifter who looks exactly like them, but acts differently.

Mild sci-fi reference as replacement would require advanced tech or magic to have taken place, although the exact phrase is much more commonly used where such a switch has not actually happened.

Comment: This is very popular in American English as well. I make no assertion as to its origin

Answer (score 5):

It's a [phrase](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/who+are+you+and+what+have+you+done+with) used to highlight when someone is acting out of character. In this case, Hermione who is usually a stickler for rules, is expressing enthusiasm for breaking them.